# Omnet++ lte mode 4 vector and scalar files error

Tags: omnet++, simulte

I was trying to implement the simulte provided at https://github.com/brianmc95/simulte.
I am using omnet 5.0 and inet 3.4 as recommended in the readme file.
I am using veins 4.5 and sumo 0.29.0 and working on windows 10.
So while integrating all of these together,there was no error but while simulating mode 4 and mode 4 validation present in simulte,i am getting errors with vector and scalar files.
I am attaching screenshots.
Kindly help me with this.

[image: First image shows vector file error]

[image: Second image shows scalar file error]

[image]

[error in command window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPYjG.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the `omnetpp.ini` file included in version 1.1.0 of Brian's code, your OMNeT++ simulation will try to use a file name for writing to its result files that is invalid on your machine. See [lines 14 and 15 of omnetpp.ini](https://github.com/brianmc95/simulte/blob/v1.1.0/simulations/Mode4/omnetpp.ini#L14) for how/where it is configured. Change these lines and the error should go away.

Comment: Thank you.I checked and set the recording of results to default files instead of those written in the code.And now those errors are gone.But i am left with the traci server lost error message(the one shown in the 3rd and 4th screenshot under the question).How to get rid of this?I have searched for it but haven't found a solution yet.Please check if you can help.

Comment: Would you mind opening a new question for this? Keeping things sorted will help other people who might have the same question - now or in the future.